# Can't access share sometimes and some strange performance issues

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, server-message-block, windows

I'm getting error 0x80070043 "The network name cannot be found" when accessing \\dc01 (the root), but can access shares via \\dc01\share.

When I get that error I also didn't get the network drive on hosted that server set via Group Policy, it fails with this error:

> The user 'W:' preference item in the 'GPO Name' Group Policy Object
>   did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070008 Not enough
>   storage is available to process this command.' This error was
>   suppressed.

The client is Windows Server 2012 Remote Desktop and server is 2012 too. On a VMware host.

Then I log off and on, and no issues.

Maybe related and maybe where the problem is:
When I have this issue and sometimes when I don't (the network drive is added fine) I have some strange performance issues on share/network drive:
Word, Excel and PDF files opens very slowly. Offices says "Contacting \\dc01\share..." for 20-30 sec.
Txt files don't have that problem.

I have a DC02 server also 2012 with no issues like like this.

Any tips how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I first suspected that it had something with too many sessions or users, but there are only about 15 users with max 30-40 "open files" on the servers each.
I have tried to changed NIC in RD and DC02 VMs, from E1000 to VMXNET3 (as VMware recommend). And these two servers don't seems to have a problem anymore, so I'll soon change the NIC on DC01 too, but I can't still see why that should be any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the drive mapping to the FQDN of the server, and haven't has any issues since.